# Function to replace NaN values

Tags: python, function, lambda, mean

I am trying to replace Nan value with the following code:

```
def NAfunc(df,s):

    if df[s].isnull():
        df[s]=df[s].fillna(df[s].mean())
    else:
        pass
    return df[s]
data['ColX']=data.apply(lambda x: NAfunc(x, 'ColX'), axis=1) #applying func to missing value column
```

I am getting error:

> 'float' object has no attribute 'isnull'

Could you please tell me where I am going wrong or a better function code?

Comment: Why don't you use `data['ColX'] = data['ColX'].fillna(data['ColX'].mean())`

Comment: Thats cool, but I want to try using function since there were many columns in the dataset

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using `df[s].isnull()` you can probably go for:

```
import math

def NAfunc(df,s):

    if math.isnan(df[s]):
        df[s]=df[s].fillna(df[s].mean())
    else:
        pass
    return df[s]
```

Comment: I have tried this but using in the final statement its giving me error: AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'fillna', while using this: data['ColX']=data.apply(lambda x: NAfunc(x, 'Col_X'), axis=1)

Comment: To me this means that where you are getting a pandas.df value, you are getting a float instead. You should try to view what you are calling fillna on, and verify if that data structure is what you are supposed to get in that position